# how to link Buttons in custom ui of call screen to the mesibo sdk, in incoming call and on call fragments

Tags: mesibo

Here https://mesibo.com/documentation/ui-modules/android/calls/#using-mesibo-calls-fragment information regarding customization is available but I am unable to find ways to provide the functionality to buttons in the custom screen. please help on this https://mesibo.com/documentation/ui-modules/android/calls/#mesibocall_getaudiocallfragment

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked here, you can take it as a refrence

https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-android-beta/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/mesibo/messenger/AudioIncomingFragment.java